# Product of numbers $\pm\sqrt{1}\pm\sqrt{2}\pm\cdots\pm\sqrt{n}$ is integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Prove that the product of the $2^n$ numbers $\pm\sqrt{1}\pm\sqrt{2}\pm\cdots\pm\sqrt{n}$ is an integer.

I want to consider the polynomial $P(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_{2^n})$, where the $a_i$'s are the $2^n$ numbers. The desired product is the constant term of the polynomial. Can we show that this polynomial have some simple form?

Comment: Try finding an inductive proof.  Suppose that $P_n$ is the given product; can you find a formula for $P_{n+1}$ in terms of $P_n$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: Let $P_n(x)$ be your polynomial. Then show $P_{n+1}(x)=P_n(x-\sqrt{n+1})P_n(x+\sqrt{n+1})$, and show inductively that $P_n(x)$ always has only integer coefficients.