# Product of numbers $\pm \sqrt{1} \pm \sqrt{2} \pm \dots \pm \sqrt{100}$ is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Let $A$ be the product of $2^{100}$ numbers of the form 
$$\pm \sqrt{1} \pm \sqrt{2} \pm \dots \pm \sqrt{100}$$
Show that $A$ is an integer, and moreover, a perfect square.

I found a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072169/product-of-numbers-pm-sqrt1-pm-sqrt2-pm-cdots-pm-sqrtn-is-integer), but the induction doesn't seem to show that $A$ is a perfect square. And I think we can generalize the following problem: if $n$ is a perfect square then $A$ is a perfect square, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same argument can be used to show that the product of the $2^{n-1}$ numbers $\sqrt{1} \pm \sqrt{2} \pm \cdots \pm \sqrt{n}$ is an integer.

Then your number is exactly the square of this product.

Comment: Those $2^{100}$ numbers are totally different (from those $2^{99}$ numbers). Their **amount** is indeed a square of the previous amount, but that's about the only obvious fact here... isn't it?

Comment: @barakmanos "Totally different"?  Every term of primitiveroot's product is either equal to a term of my product, or $-1$ times a term of my product.  Since the number of signs, $2^{n-1}$, is even (for $n>1$), my conclusion follows.  And no, $2^{100} \neq (2^{99})^2$.